# An approach to read data table

Tags: r

I am searching for a way where I can read these line of texts into df in a column so that I can do practicing on it.

```
some text sample 1
some text sample  2 3
some more text 's sample here and then
another one
How to add text to df using read.table
```

Output:

```
                                   text
1                     some text sample 1
2                  some text sample  2 3
3    some more text 's sample here and then
4                            another one
5 How to add text to df using read.table
```

Thank for helping me out.

Comment: Have you tried with `readLines('file.txt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `readLines` to read each line and then convert to `data.frame`.  In this way, we can be sure that it will read a line as a whole and doesn't depend upon any separation (in case if present)

```
data.frame(text = readLines('file.txt'))
#                                    text
#1                     some text sample 1
#2                  some text sample  2 3
#3 some more text 's sample here and then
#4                            another one
#5 How to add text to df using read.table
```

---

We can also use `read.table` with a different `sep`

```
df <- read.table('file.txt', header = FALSE, col.names = 'txt', sep=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
#Code
df <- read.delim(file='myfile.txt',header=F,stringsAsFactors = F,sep='\t')
```

Output:

```
df
                                      V1
1                     some text sample 1
2                  some text sample  2 3
3 some more text 's sample here and then
4                            another one
5 How to add text to df using read.table
```